# Application services model for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, architecture, frameworks

Is there any twisted-like framework for NodeJS that has the following (or is close to):

- An `Application` object that consists of services and stores some globally accessible data
- A `Service` object, pluggable into an `Application` and optionally wrapping other services
- Some kind of dependency control?
- Some cron-like tasks runner?

By using a form of `Application.start()`, one initializes all the services: say, a webserver service, an API endpoint, a DB connection, etc.

Comment: I don't know of any, and that's why I've been developing my own: https://github.com/InJoin/framework (see branch 0.3.0 - also, feel free to join me)

Comment: I'd prefer a specific solution which's pluggable :) Then.. coming soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[nodejs-kickapp](https://github.com/kolypto/nodejs-kickapp)

- Application, which wraps hierarchical Services
- Service, which can start/stop asynchronously
- Extensible